# VS2010 Hotkey Name for Duplicating Line

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 what is the hotkey binding **name** for duplicating a line in the keyboard editor? I want to change it from

```
 CTRL + C / CTRL + V
```

to

```
CTRL + SHIFT + DOWN
```

Then I can be happy and content :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating `Macro`.  To create the macro, follow these steps.

1. Go to the macro explorer (Tools->Macros->Macro Explorer)
2. Right Click `My Macros` and click `New Module`.
3. In the module created copy and paste the code.

   ```
   Sub DuplicateLine()
     Dim line As String
     DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(0)
     DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(True)
     line = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text
     DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
     DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine()
     DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(0)
     DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = line
   End Sub
   ```

Now just assign a keyboard shortcut to it:

1. Go to Tools->Options
2. Under Environment, click Keyboard
3. In the "Show Commands Containing" textbox, enter "duplicate" (this according to the name you gave the module.)
4. Choose "Text Editor" from the "Use new shortcut in" list
5. Set focus in the "Press shortcut keys" textbox and hit the combination on the keyboard you wish to use for it (Ctrl+Shift+D in my case)
6. Hit the "Assign" button
7. Hit the OK button

**Source: ** http://www.herrodius.com/blog/52